# open alertDialog in kotlin, how to set both message with radio buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, radiobuttonlist

Trying to open a alertDialog in kotlin,  the dialog needs to show title and some text message and some radio button list.

made the dialog part work, but cannot set the message (body), if set the message then the radio button will not be shown(???).

I guess this might be limitation of the alertDialog, or anyone knows work around?

```
fun openAlertDialog(title: String, alertMessage: String, items: ArrayList<String>) {
    val poistion = 0
    val alertDilogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.myDialogeTheme)
    alertDilogBuilder.setTitle(title)

    //alertDilogBuilder.setMessage(alertMessage)   //<== if setMessage the radio button will not show

           .setSingleChoiceItems(list, poistion, object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, index: Int) {
                    onSelectedCategory(items[index])

                    Toast.makeText(activity.applicationContext,
                                    items[index],  
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            })

        alertDialog = alertDilogBuilder.create()
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, “Ok", {
            dialogInterface, i ->
            onSelectedCategory(items[0])
        })
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Cancel", {
            dialogInterface, k ->
            dialogInterface.dismiss()  
        })
        alertDialog!!.show()
}
```

Comment: You may consider using `setView`, but there will be much more work to do.

Comment: right @BakaWaii, just try to not have to build another view but simply use the alertDialog.